# How to slice an array up until a certain element

Tags: javascript, arrays, slice

I have an array containing strings and objects. The strings act as the "title" while the objects that followed them are the "contents". It is arranged this way for virtualization purposes. Here's what I got so far

```
const test = [
    "string 1",
    { prop1: "string 1 obj first" },
    { prop1: "string 1 obj" },
    { prop1: "string 1 obj" },
    { prop1: "string 1 obj" },
    { prop1: "string 1 obj last" },
    "string 2",
    { prop1: "string 2 obj first" },
    { prop1: "string 2 obj" },
    { prop1: "string 2 obj" },
    { prop1: "string 2 obj last" },
    "string 3",
    { prop1: "string 3 obj first" },
    { prop1: "string 3 obj" },
    { prop1: "string 3 obj" },
    { prop1: "string 3 obj" },
    { prop1: "string 3 obj" },
    { prop1: "string 3 obj" },
    { prop1: "string 3 obj last" },
]

const result = test.reduce((acc, curr, i, arr) => {
    const next = arr[i+1]

    // with Title
    if (typeof curr === 'string') {
        if (typeof next === 'object' && next !== null) {
            // get the index for the next title from here
            const nextTitleIndex = test.slice(i + 1).findIndex((item) => typeof item === 'string');
            // slice the array from this point up to the index of the next title (not included)
            const objects = test.slice(i + 1, nextTitleIndex === -1 ? undefined : nextTitleIndex + 1)

            console.log({ nextTitleIndex, objects })
        }
    }

    return acc
}, [])
```

I need to get all the objects in between the current iteration's title and the next title along the line. (in the example, the objects between "string 1" and "string 2", etc.)

The first and last iterations work as intended, with the `objects` variable containing five/seven objects from `first` to `last`. However, the middle iterations dont produce the desired values for `objects`, it becomes an empty array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify what the end result should be so I pick two for you:

An array of arrays with the first element of an array being the title:

```
const result = [];
test.forEach((s) => {
  if(typeof s === 'string') {
    result.push([]);
  }
  result[result.length - 1].push(s); // access error when the test data is not structured correctly
});

console.log(result); // [['string 1', { prop1: "string 1 obj first" }, ...],['string 2', ...], ...]
```

An object with the keys being the title and the values being an array of the content objects:

```
const result = {};
let key = undefined;
test.forEach((s) => {
  if(typeof s === 'string') {
    key = s;
    result[key] = [];
  } else {
    result[key].push(s); // access error when the test data is not structured correctly
  }  
});

console.log(result); // {string 1: [{ prop1: "string 1 obj first" }, ...], string 2: [...], ...}
```

Comment: the result should just be an array of the objects. I made a different implementation but thank you for your answer